# Is it possible to run multiple nginx docker containers on the same host?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Is is possible, using only docker-compose, to mount multiple nginx containers on the same host machine, with each container sharing port 80?

I want to tidy up a system that runs multiple applications on the same host. 
Each application consists of several linked docker containers tied together with a docker-compose file, and each application is exposed to the world using the host system's nginx as a reverse proxy. So far, so good.

Each time I add a new docker application, I have to add a new nginx.conf file for that application to the host nginx, but I'd prefer bundling the nginx config  with the app's docker-compose file as an nginx container, and thus have each app cleanly maintain everything it needs in containers. However, each nginx container needs to listen on port 80, so only the first one can bind. The host nginx can listen for several web applications on port 80, but can multiple nginx instances do the same?

UPDATED :

So it seems this isn't strictly possible. The goal is to have as much application-specific nginx config bundled with the application, so I'm trying a solution where an app still spins up its own nginx container with that logic, while the host nginx handles only url routing to the app nginx. Not sure about performance, but this greatly reduces app entanglement with the host.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It seems Ngnix is load balancing between your containers and as such lives a layer above your containers and can't be managed by them.

Comment: you can run as many as required with different ports. But what is the need to run multiple nginx container. run one container with multiple server blocks to proxy_pass to as many applications as required. I see only server blocks with include proerty is required rather than running multiple c.ontainers

Comment: @JinnaBalu The point is to keep all config neatly tucked away in one docker-compose.yml file per project. I suspected this wasn't possible, I just wanted to ask to be thorough before I gave up on it.

Answer (score 27):

Even though it has been a few years, I thought I might as well answer it for others who come across this issue.

Unfortunately, no. It's not possible to have multiple containers on the same port. This is due to the nature of the operating system. But I think I can understand what you are trying to do. You want to have multiple custom config web applications.

The best way to do this is through a **[reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)**. What a reverse proxy does is that it allows you to forward requests from the main port (such as 80 and 433) to web-servers on other ports or addresses. Assuming that all of your containers have their own instance of Nginx (or any other web server) in them with your config and code. There are two ways to do this.

In docker, the easiest way to do this is through the [nginx-proxy project](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy). Just by adding a variable to the environment in your docker-compose, a managed nginx container will automatically forward your requests to the set site. This seems like what you would want to do since it requires only a docker-compose.

You can also manage this yourself. Keep all your sites listening on other ports in nginx, and have one main nginx container listening on 80 and 433 that forwards the requests using reverse proxies you create to another port.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Really old post, but for those arriving from search, you might be able to do this in 2023 by using this compose config:

```
    version: "3"
    services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        ports:
          - "80"
```

Notice:

```
    ports:
     - "80"
```

This is not a mistake. Instead of typical port mapping, e.g. `80:80` by only specifying a single port, docker compose *should* use virtual port sharding to dynamically map requests using round robin to each instance of the service that is running. So to run three instances, you should in theory be able to do this:

`docker-compose up --scale nginx=3`

That should run 3 instances of nginx. If you defined another service in your compose file, `expressjs` for example, you could also take advantage of the same strategy by using a simple nginx config that uses docker's embedded dynamic dns.

```
    # nginx.conf
    user  nginx;
    
    events {
        worker_connections   1000;
    }
    http {
            server {
                  listen 80;
                  location / {
                    proxy_pass http://expressjs:3000;
                  }
            }
    }
```

And then define your compose like this:

```
    version: "3"
    
    services:
      expressjs:
        image: expressjs:latest
        ports:
          - "3000"
        depends_on:
          - nginx
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        ports:
          - "80"
```

I haven't tested this but it should work in theory.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/